# Counting NA characters of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have the following matrix:

```
  V1  V2  V3   V4  
[1,] "d" "e" "i"  "NA"
[2,] "j" "e" "i"  "NA"
[3,] "j" "n" "k"  "l" 
[4,] "j" "k" "l"  "m" 
[5,] "j" "k" "i"  "NA"
[6,] "o" "n" "NA" "NA"
```

I am trying to count the number elements per row that is not NA, but all of the usual ways like `!is.na(MATRIX)` are not working. I am always getting the answer to be 4. I presume this is because the program is viewing `"NA"` as a character, but I do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'NA'` is not `NA_character_` so `is.na` does not work. Just use

```
rowSums(MATRIX != 'NA')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the NAs are character strings, convert them to real NA with `mat[mat=="NA"] <- NA` and then use the solution in Sotos' comment